# Desktop image drag&drop upload crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I got a form for uploading images through ajaxForm. I have implemented a function so users can drop photos from desktop (HTML5 drag&drop). Every thing works fine if photo is "small" - lets say 2mb. The problem occuress when I try to upload photos that are larger then 4mb. Chrome browser crashes.

AjaxForm

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
        iframe: true,
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            $("#post .button.save").prop("disabled",true).val("Uploading...");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#FilePhotoString").val("");
            $("#post").css({
                "background": 'url(' + result + ') no-repeat center center',
                "display": "block",
                "height": $("body").height(),
                "background-size": "cover"
            });
            $("img").attr("src",result).load(function() { 
               $('input[name="ImageFilePath"]').attr('value', result);
               $("#post .button.save.now").prop("disabled",false).val("Publish now");
               $("#post .button.save.later").prop("disabled",false).val("Publish later");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Drop

```
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',function(event) { event.preventDefault(); },false);
document.querySelector('#content').addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(evt) { 
                $("#FilePhotoString").val(evt.target.result);   
            $("#uploadForm").submit();  
        };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}, false);
```

Result returned on success is just path of uploaded photo. Any ideas what can I do so browser will not crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about taking another approach, like using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) and sending a file instead of a string.

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById('#uploadForm'));
data.append('theNameYouWantToSend', event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
```

then send an ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url:'theurl',
    type:'post',
    data: data,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it isnt a jquery/ajax/browser problem. If you are using an apache server for example check the "upload_max_filesize = 2M" located at your php.ini.

The default size is 2mb so it fits you're problem well. The server send a timeout if you try to upload more than 2mb.

Comment: Its not server side problem. We got permittion for 10M.